# Probability of being included in majority

Tags: probability

There are 100 people including me.

If each person selects between party A and party B to join,

Then how will be the probability that my party be the majority?

Is it 50%? Or bigger than 50%?

If the answer is 50%, there is an additional question.

I'm the owner of a casino.
If I make a game like I explained above(the majority lose, and the minority win double of their bet)

It is clear that the casino will make big profit in the long run.
But how can the casino win if the probability is exactly 50%?

Comment: Try it out on $2$ persons including you, and draw conclusions.

Comment: As you point out, it depends on the overall statistics.  If everybody chooses party $A$ then the answer is $1$, to take an extreme case.

Comment: Suppose you are the first person to be selected to join a party, exist 2 cases you join to A or you join to B (probability 1/2).
Now you need find the probability that at least 50 persons of 99 joint to you party.
If you use the total probability theorem you gonna note that the probability is 1/2

Comment: With $100$ people, there is the possibility of a $50:50$ split